# Compatibility of purchased DVD burners with Dell PC

Tags: power-supply, dvd, burning, dell-vostro

my name is Kimon and I have recently asked from my father, Vasileios, to buy through the site with the URLs shown below two of the DVD burners they sell, the Optiarc AD-5280S-CB-PLUS and the Plextor PX-891SAF, both of which arrived two weeks after the purchase, and I would like to express a few queries that I have, as the store from which we ordered the products, RunTechMedia, has not replied to those same questions.

https://www.runtechmedia.com/product.asp?sku=Plextor-PX-891SAF&a=&title=Plextor-Burner

https://www.runtechmedia.com/product.asp?sku=5280S-CB-PLUS&a=&title=Optiarc-Burner

To begin with, I would like you to tell me if they will be compatible with my European Dell Vostro 200 PC, given that my Region 2 current burner had also written on its sticker that it required the same voltage to function as the items shown in the URLs above do, specifically 5 and 12 Volts, but there is a difference in the corresponding current, namely for 5 Volts my old drive uses 1.7 Amps, while both of the newly acquired burners need 1.5 Amps and for 12 Volts mine uses 1.5 Amps and the Optiarc and Plextor 2.5 Amps, always according to their respective stickers. I had hoped that changing the Region would be the only thing I would have to worry about and do in order to use the burners and before I read the stickers I was under the impression, certainty even, that power requirements would not differ overseas. Therefore, I would like to be informed of whether there is a risk of damaging or, worse, destroying these USA devices if I connect them to my European PC. If there is, I would like to know what a possible solution would be. I have heard of power transformers and adapters before, but these seem to work with whole computers and not parts of them. So, I would like to learn if there is anything that can be done, like a device that anyone can recommend me for such cases, as the burners cost my father too much to be shipped to our country, to just watch them sitting on my office's desk.

In addition, I would like to know if anyone has a clue on whether or not the burners sold by RunTechMedia are new or used and, if they have been used, again, if it would be safe to install them on my desktop computer. The reasons why I am asking that question is because I assume RunTechMedia is a legit retail seller, and, although the products my father bought from them do not show any signs of wear, but, instead, they appear to be in perfect, flawless condition, one of the two has been manufactured in 2013, which would make it extremely hard to find now as new, and neither of them contained a box, as is the case with new products. If any people have a buyer's experience with them, their opinion would be greatly appreciated and desirable.

Finally, I would like to thank you all in advance for the time you spent reading this post, for the length of which I apologise, as well as for any help and reply you may give, which I look forward to receiving!

Edit: At last, a clear, helpful response. To think that I even chatted with Plextor's technical service and the reply I got by an employee was, if I can recall correctly something like "I'm no electrical expert but I am unsure that it (their burner) will work on your system". If there is strong evidence to back up the theory about SATA connectors being universal power wise, then Plextor is quite wrong. Also, Vinpower Digital did not reply at all! And no, I have only 1 HDD and 1 burner, namely the default configuration by Dell, save for the burner which I intend to replace. I am currently a guest, so please let me know if and how I can vote for your answer this way. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system's power supply should convert from whatever your wall voltage standard is to the proper +5/+12v needed by the devices behind it.

AFAIK there is no such thing as "European SATA" power connectors or power standard, for example.  So, this is not something you have to worry about, you should just be able to connect the devices.

You *do* have to worry about your local power voltage when replacing the entire power supply in your system, as you need to set the voltage properly.  But as far as attaching devices to an existing power supply, they are all standard.

The amps are normal to vary from device to device and also not something you typically need to worry about.  You just need to keep the number of watts well under the total number of watts your system is rated for, and is usually only something you need to be really concerned about if you are trying to something like connect 4 or more hard drives to a system or connecting a high-powered graphics card.